# Drool's Rule is holding state and fire rules when it shouldn't

Tags: drools

I'm having an issue where a rule isn't updating state and firing when it shouldn't I only want the rule to fire when both switches are open.

```
For example:

In the following order I

open switcha
close switcha
open switchb
```

It fires the rule, when it shouldn't as switcha is closed. It appears as soon as
Switch( name == "switcha", status == "Open ) becomes true, it holds this state even when closing the switch again.

```
rule "Electrical Circuit Status"
  when
    Switch( name == "switcha", status == "Open" )
and
    Switch( name == "switchb", status == "Open" )

  then   // Raise Alert

 ** Didn't write this code out as it works fine

end
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely misunderstanding working memory state. However since your question is extremely light on details, I'm going to make several assumptions in my explanation which I'll lay out below.

Let's assume that we have two switches that are in the following states:

- `Switch( name == "switcha", status == "Closed")`
- `Switch( name == "switchb", status == "Closed")`

We pass these switches as-is into our rules.

When we're operating in Cloud mode, rules are executed during an instant in time rather than over time (which would be Stream mode.) Cloud mode is the default mode and the mode that the majority of applications leverage. Since you make no mention of event streams, I'm going to assume you're running in this mode. (If you have no idea what I'm talking about, you're also likely to be running in Cloud mode; Stream mode is a relatively new addition.) I'm also going to assume a stateful session.

When we call `fireAllRules`, Drools will look at the rule inputs and figure out which rules have conditions which match those conditions. It will take that subset of rules, figure out their ordering based on salience and natural order, and then execute them.

As it executes those rules, you can modify the rule inputs in several ways.

- Call `insert`. This adds a new fact into working memory.
- Call `modify`. This changes the existing fact data.
- Call `update`. This also changes the existing fact data.
- Change the data on the object directly, eg via a getter or a setter.

Depending on how you change the data, this may or may not change how your rules are evaluated.

**If you change the data directly**, for example via a getter or a setter, this does not cause any re-evaluation of the rules. Any changes are functionally "invisible" to the drools engine. The same rules that were initially identified as being matches are still fired, even if the condition is no longer true because you updated the data in a way that did not cause Drools to re-evaluate these conditions.

**If you call `update`**, Drools will re-evaluate the entire rule scope. This is functionally equivalent to changing the data and then refiring the rules again, from the top. Drools will look at all of the rules using the new data in working memory, and redo the process of collecting matches, ordering them, and firing them. It is *extremely* easy to get into a "looping" situation using `update` calls.

**If you call `insert`** you are adding a new piece of data to working memory. Drools will do a partial re-evaluation of the rules to figure out if there are any new rules which are eligible to fire, or if the previous matches are now invalidated. It will not re-fire any rules which previously matched and were fired. Similarly, **if you call `modify`**, you change the existing rule input object properties in some way and Drools will partially re-evaluate based on those changed conditions.

(This is simplified. You can learn more about the nuances by reading the source code or the documentation.)

Since you only show one partial rule, and only say that it fires even "when closing the switch again" though without explaining *how* the switch was closed, I can come up with several possible ways of triggering this condition based on the previous explanation of how you can change data with (or without) re-evaluating rule conditions.

For example, if you change the switch state by calling a `setStatus("Closed")` method, rather than by using `modify`, then the rule will not be aware of the new state.

```
rule "change switch state invisibly"
when
  // some conditions
  $b: Switch( name == "switchb", status == "Open" )
then
  $b.setStatus("Closed"); 
end

rule "Electrical Circuit Status"
  Switch( name == "switcha", status == "Open" ) // let's assume this is true
  Switch( name == "switchb", status == "Open" ) // Also still true!
then
  // show alert
end
```

Since you change the state using `setStatus` instead of `modify`, Drools didn't re-evaluate subsequent rule matches and kept the previous matches. Therefore the condition remained true.

To fix, you'd either use `modify` or (less recommended) `update` working memory after your change (with the understanding that *all* rules would be re-evaluated.)

```
modify ($b) {
  setStatus("Closed")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. The data is flowing from physical switches into a data object. Such as a light switch. When both switches are open the circuit is open (light goes out). The data streams the position of the switch when changed physically. As you have mentioned it's not re evaluating the entire rule hence still firing even though one switch may be closed.  I'm not sure how I will be able to use the update when the data is flowing from a physical device, sounds like I need it to re evaluate the rule with every switch change. Still new, appreciate the help! Ill do some reading.

Comment: I see Drools is not helpful when we have a set of rules depend on the result of a previous rule. Even developers need think carefully about update situation & avoid infinite loop, now a non-technical person surely cannot understand/maintain these rules

Comment: I'm a little mystified how you came to that conclusion, @BabyishTank. The business analysts at my previous company were perfectly capable of understanding rules. But yes you do need to be aware of looping constructs whenever you rerun a set of rules, just like whenever you write a for or while loop.